# Disable time in End date in React date picker up to where start time is selected

Tags: react-hooks, react-datepicker

I want to disable  previous selected start date and time in the End date, I managed to disable date but not time.
I am using [react date picker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) and  [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mirzakhani-jcufdh?file=/src/App.js), Thanks in advance.